# -1 left shift by 31

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
System.out.println((-1<<31));
```

Why this is giving output   -2147483648

I know -1<<31 will give 10000000000000000000000000000000, so it should give ans `(int)Math.pow(2,31)`  that is equals to 2147483648

Comment: it gives 10000000000000000000000000000000 not 100000000000000000 which is negative value

Comment: 2147483648 and -2147483648 are the same number modulo 2^32, but -2147483648 is the canonical interpretation for 2's complement numbers.

Comment: @Ronaldo7 Consider accepting an answer. Or aren't you happy with one of the answers ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-1<<31` gives `10000000000000000000000000000000` which is `-2147483648`, not `2147483648`. Note that the left bit is the sign bit, so if it's 1, this is a negative number.

BTW, `1<<31` would also give you `-2147483648`, since `2147483648` is higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. On the other hand, `1L<<31` would give you `2147483648`, since the result would be a `long`.

Comment: @Ronaldo7 How is that comment related to the original question?

Answer (score 4):

> I know -1<<31 will give 100000000000000000, so it should give ans (int)Math.pow(2,31) that is equals to 2147483648

That would be the case if `int` was a two's complement *unsigned* primitive; but `int` is signed.

You are correct in the fact that in binary this indeed gives what you say; however, since this is a signed two's complement primitive, the result will be x(0) * 2^0 + x(1) * 2^1 + ... + x(n-2) * 2^(n-2) **- x(n-1) * 2^(n-1)** (minus, not plus), where `x(y)` is the value of the y-th bit, counting from 0.

Hence your result.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays in most architectures numbers are stored in 2-complements, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

So your result is correct. The sign bit is set and all the resting zeros (because 2-complement) makes that the most negative number for that data type, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Most_negative_number).

### Thinking in 2-complements

```
-1 is represented by 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

31 shifts to the left yields

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 which represents -2.147.483.648
```

Comment: No, it indeed gives -2147483648, which is exactly -2^31.

Comment: You are right. I flipped the signs. What I meant is valid for positive numbers. The max number is 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647) and the min number is -2^31 (-2.147.483.648).